# Drop-down "selectbox" list after click row in table

Tags: javascript, php, css, ajax

I am looking for a solution opening the drop-down list by right clicking right mouse button.

More details :

1) MySQL table displayed using ajax
2) I choose a row
3) I click mouse right button on the row
4) I see a small selectbox list with the option to edit this row

I will be gratefull for your help

Comment: try this https://editor.datatables.net/examples/inline-editing/submitData.html

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<div oncontextmenu="myFunction()">

myFunction() {
    alert('Success');
}
```